# Routing problems with React Router Dom V6 and netcup

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom, web-hosting

My vite react-ts application works fine on localhost but always throws an 404 on netcup webhosting 1000 package.
The Home page is shown correctly, but I cannot navigate to the About page by button as link.

[image]

This files are on the server:
[image]

Here is my react router v6 implementation:

#### main.tsx

```js
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

#### App.tsx

```js
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import About from './pages/About';
import Home from './pages/Home';

const App: React.FC = (): JSX.Element => {
    return (
        <>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
            </Routes>
        </>
    );
};

export default App;
```

#### Home.tsx

```js
const Home= () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Button variant="primary" href="/about"> More about me</Button>
        </div>
    );
export default Home;
```

#### About.tsx

```js
const About = () => {
    return (
        <div>
           <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
        </div>
    );
};

export default About;
```

I tried to

- use a minimal frontend with only button click
- research about netcup webhosting 1000 bundle
- use react router dom v5
- use react router dom v6

Nothing could solve my problem.

I could not figure out if netcup webhosting 1000 is not made for routing or anything like that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `v6` or `v5` which is it?

Comment: The server should be configured to serve your root index.html file. See the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) to get a general idea what different configurations different server environments need. Consult the netcup docs. Internal navigation should work regardless since it is client-side... *how* exactly are you trying to navigate to the about page?

Comment: i am using it is react router v6.

Comment: I updated my question based on your comment @DrewReese

Comment: What is a `Button` component and why does it have `href` attribute? You should rather use `Link` instead

Comment: What Konrad said. The `href` is likely causing a page request to the server and reloading the page. Use a `Link` or use the `Button` with an `onClick` handler that uses the `navigate` function in order to navigate client-side. You'll still need to address the server issues so you can navigate directly to a sub-route or reload the page manually.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility the netcup webhosting 1000 package is hosting your web page as a static site like in GitHub Page, so the React router don't work with BrowserRouter component, you may need to use the HashRouter component like:

```
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <HashRouter>
            <App />
        </HashRouter>
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Or there is other solution fix like creating the _redirect file in public folder but i am not sure about how it work on your hosting.